# Hide/Show Columns in an HTML Table (with multiple column in the header)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Can anyone help please, I am trying to hide/show my html table columns, my table has three rows in the header and need to hide/show the columns of the second row with the contained small rows, I used an example found here in Stackoverflow but still can't succeed to do the job, my code is as following:

```js
        $(function() {
  // on init
  $(".table-hideable .hide-col").each(HideColumnIndex);

  // on click
  $('.hide-column').click(HideColumnIndex)

  function HideColumnIndex() {
    var $el = $(this);
    var $cell = $el.closest('th,td')
    var $table = $cell.closest('table')

   
    var colIndex = $cell[0].cellIndex + 1;

    // find and hide col index
    $table.find("tbody tr, thead tr")
      .children(":nth-child(" + colIndex + ")")
      .addClass('hide-col');
      
    // show restore footer
    $table.find(".footer-restore-columns").show()
  }

  // restore columns footer
  $(".restore-columns").click(function(e) {
    var $table = $(this).closest('table')
    $table.find(".footer-restore-columns").hide()
    $table.find("th, td")
      .removeClass('hide-col');

  })

  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
    trigger: 'hover'
  })

})
```

```css
        body {
  padding: 15px;
}

.table-hideable td,
.table-hideable th {
  width: auto;
  transition: width .5s, margin .5s;
}

.btn-condensed.btn-condensed {
  padding: 0 5px;
  box-shadow: none;
}


/* use class to have a little animation */
.hide-col {
  width: 0px !important;
  height: 0px !important;
  display: block !important;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  border: none !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootswatch/3.3.7/paper/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<table class="table table-condensed table-hover table-bordered table-striped table-hideable">

  <thead>
      <tr>
      <th colspan="4" > 
        
        TOP </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
      <th colspan="2" > <button class="pull-right btn btn-default btn-condensed hide-column" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Hide Column">
          <i class="fa fa-eye-slash"></i>  
        </button>
        
        A </th>
      <th  colspan="2" > <button class="pull-right btn btn-default btn-condensed hide-column" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Hide Column">
          <i class="fa fa-eye-slash"></i>  
        </button>
       
        B
      </th>
 
      </tr>
       <tr>
       <th>
         
         AA </th>
       <th class="hide-col"> 
        
         AB   </th>
       <th>  
        
         BB </th>
      <th > 
        
        BC </th>

       </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td>Home</td>
      <td>Index</td>
      <td>ActionResult</td>
      <td>Authorize</td>
      
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Client</td>
      <td>Index</td>
      <td>ActionResult</td>
      <td>Authorize</td>
     
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Client</td>
      <td>Edit</td>
      <td>ActionResult</td>
      <td>Authorize</td>
     
    </tr>

  </tbody>
  <tfoot class="footer-restore-columns">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="4"><a class="restore-columns" href="#">Some columns hidden - click to show all</a></th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```js
$(function() {
  // on click
  $('.hide-column').click(HideColumns)
  
  // on init
  $('.hide-column').eq(0).trigger( "click" );

  function HideColumns() {
    var $el = $(this);
    var $cell = $el.closest('th,td')
    var $table = $cell.closest('table')

    var colIndex = 0;
    var colSpan = 0;

    $cell.parent().children().each(function(index) {
      if ($(this).is($cell)) {
        colSpan = parseInt($cell.attr("colspan") || 1);
        return false;
      } else {
        colIndex += parseInt($(this).attr("colspan") || 1);
      };
    });

    // find and hide col index
    for (var i = colIndex; i < (colIndex + colSpan); i++) {
      $table.find("tbody tr, thead :nth-child(3)")
        .children(":nth-child(" + (i + 1) + ")")
        .addClass('hide-col');
    };
    
    //always show first header
    $table.find("thead :nth-child(1)").children().removeClass('hide-col');
    
    //hide clicked cell
    $cell.addClass('hide-col');

    // show restore footer
    $table.find(".footer-restore-columns").show()
  }

  // restore columns footer
  $(".restore-columns").click(function(e) {
    var $table = $(this).closest('table')
    $table.find(".footer-restore-columns").hide()
    $table.find("th, td")
      .removeClass('hide-col');

  })

  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
    trigger: 'hover'
  })

})
```

```css
body {
  padding: 15px;
}

.table-hideable td,
.table-hideable th {
  width: auto;
  transition: width .5s, margin .5s;
}

.btn-condensed.btn-condensed {
  padding: 0 5px;
  box-shadow: none;
}


/* use class to have a little animation */

.hide-col {
  width: 0px !important;
  height: 0px !important;
  display: block !important;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  border: none !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootswatch/3.3.7/paper/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


  <table class="table table-condensed table-hover table-bordered table-striped table-hideable">

    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="4">

          TOP </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2"> <button class="pull-right btn btn-default btn-condensed hide-column" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Hide Column" data>
          <i class="fa fa-eye-slash"></i>  
        </button> A </th>
        <th colspan="2"> <button class="pull-right btn btn-default btn-condensed hide-column" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Hide Column">
          <i class="fa fa-eye-slash"></i>  
        </button> B
        </th>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>

          AA </th>
        <th class="hide-col">

          AB </th>
        <th>

          BB </th>
        <th>

          BC </th>

      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

      <tr>
        <td>Home</td>
        <td>Index</td>
        <td>ActionResult</td>
        <td>Authorize</td>

      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Client</td>
        <td>Index</td>
        <td>ActionResult</td>
        <td>Authorize</td>

      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Client</td>
        <td>Edit</td>
        <td>ActionResult</td>
        <td>Authorize</td>

      </tr>

    </tbody>
    <tfoot class="footer-restore-columns">
      <tr>
        <th colspan="4"><a class="restore-columns" href="#">Some columns hidden - click to show all</a></th>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
```

As `th` elements with `colspan` are being used, a different approach is needed. Instead of only considering the current column index, the above solution finds the range of indexes of `td` cells within `tbody` according to the `th` where the button was clicked (`$cell`).

To hide that span of columns, it first loops through the 2nd row of the table, adding each `colspan` to `colIndex` until it gets to `$cell`. The `td` indexes to hide on each row are then from `colIndex` to `colIndex` + the `colspan` of `$cell` ([1-based in jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)).

Comment: Hi sbgib, still have an issue while implementing this solution, when i start hiding the columns from the right it works fine, but when i start from the left, i can see the issue; some cells get hidden even if not needed to be, can i send to you the code please ?

Comment: How has it been changed from the working demo? If you can upload it somewhere I can take a quick look.

Comment: sure, this is the link to it:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65288649/hide-and-show-html-table-columns

Comment: [Try like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65302846/2687204).